# Graphic card replacement

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop

Someone gave me an older DELL Precision 390. It has an ATI FireGL V7600. I'm looking for a replacement because it gets really hot really fast and its fan is very noisy. I need something one the cheaper side and that doesn't use a lot of power. I not looking for something super powerful, I just need to be able to use [Sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/) seamlessly.

I was thinking about going with a XFX HD 6000 Radeon HD 6450.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete system, or just the graphics card?

Comment: If you'd like to buy yourself some time with that card, I bet reapplying thermal paste/pads might keep things cool.

Comment: Just the graphic card. I might try the paste!

Comment: This would void an warranty, but you might be able to get an 3rd party water cooling kit and install it.  Definitely, the quietest way to go.